# Can we define static class member inside constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, static, hashmap

Say I have a static member defined in header file like:

```
static QHash<QString,int> flagColorsMap;
```

How can I define the hashmap inside the constructor that is in the cpp file. If I do the following:

```
Classname::flagColorsMap.insert("xyz",22);
```

it gives **compile error** :: undefined reference to Classname::flagColorMap.

Comment: Have you initialized `flagColorsMap` ?

Comment: That's a linker error.   Try adding a `QHash<QString,int> Classname::flagColorsMap` to define the static member, in one and only one source file that has visibility of (e.g. includes) the class definition.

Comment: Why are you using class qualificator?

Comment: Then you somehow misinterpreted or mis-applied my advice.  The substance of the answer you subsequently accepted (after it was edited due to you also saying it was "not working")  is the same advice, and the edit was simply an example.

Comment: @Peter I completely agree with you. I retract my previous statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .cpp file put this line:

```
QHash<QString,int> Classname::flagColorsMap;
```

Edited: 
Please check this really simple example of static QHash member initialization: create new Qt Quick project and edit MainWindow class:

```
// mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    static QHash<QString,int> flagColorsMap;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And source file:

```
// mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

QHash<QString,int> MainWindow::flagColorsMap;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    MainWindow::flagColorsMap.insert("xyz",22);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    qDebug() << "Value=" << flagColorsMap.value("xyz");
    delete ui;
}
```

Is it still does not work?

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: Could you provide some bigger part of your code? Such initialization works for me.

Comment: You have not done any initialization.

Comment: What I am doing is QHash<QString,int> Classname::flagColorsMap.insert("xyz",22);

Comment: @Sumeet Singh: please see my edited answer.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this compile error because you are just "delcare" flagColorsMap but not "define" it.
So define flagColorsMap in the .cpp file maybe this error will disappeared.